# Memory and calculation issues running an LLM on GPU in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, transformer-model, large-language-model

I am trying to train a local transformer model for a generic sequence modeling task on a 3090 GPU, but I am dealing with a few weird GPU issues I haven’t seen before. The model is just standard PyTorch 2.0, and I am accessing the GPU remotely via ssh.

The first and most pressing issue is that the training function is randomly freezing in the middle of some epochs. When that happens the whole kernel (testing in a notebook) becomes unresponsive, and I have to restart it. The terminal usually shows errors like the following:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-29973' coro=<WebSocketProtocol13.write_message.<locals>.wrapper() done, defined at /home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py:1090> exception=WebSocketClosedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1092, in wrapper
    await fut
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 232, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1094, in wrapper
    raise WebSocketClosedError()
tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError
[E 20:05:14.638 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in ZMQStream callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 572, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 256, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 339, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1086, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1061, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 540, in write
        self._write_buffer.append(data)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 157, in append
        b += data  # type: ignore
    BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
[E 20:05:14.639 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in zmqstream callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 634, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 663, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 572, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 256, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 339, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1086, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1061, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 540, in write
        self._write_buffer.append(data)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 157, in append
        b += data  # type: ignore
    BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
[E 20:05:14.640 NotebookApp] Exception in callback functools.partial(<function ZMQStream._update_handler.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f9f44e875b0>)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 740, in _run_callback
        ret = callback()
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 718, in <lambda>
        self.io_loop.add_callback(lambda: self._handle_events(self.socket, 0))
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 634, in _handle_events
        self._handle_recv()
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 663, in _handle_recv
        self._run_callback(callback, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 584, in _run_callback
        f = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 308, in stream_callback
        return callback(self, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 572, in _on_zmq_reply
        super()._on_zmq_reply(stream, msg)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/base/zmqhandlers.py", line 256, in _on_zmq_reply
        self.write_message(msg, binary=isinstance(msg, bytes))
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 339, in write_message
        return self.ws_connection.write_message(message, binary=binary)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1086, in write_message
        fut = self._write_frame(True, opcode, message, flags=flags)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1061, in _write_frame
        return self.stream.write(frame)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 540, in write
        self._write_buffer.append(data)
      File "/home/name/anaconda3/envs/setlist/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 157, in append
        b += data  # type: ignore
    BufferError: Existing exports of data: object cannot be re-sized
```

The model is running on a 24GB 3090 GPU, and it uses about 18-19GB of RAM.  Anyone understand what could be going on?

The second issue I am trying to understand came from one of my attempts to fix this first problem. I did a little digging and thought it might be due to a memory leak, so I started deleting the input tensors after each forward and backward pass (does this do anything?). And I also put torch.cuda.empty_cache() before each epoch.

I don’t think either of those changes helped, but the second one seems to be causing exploding gradients. Whenever I ran the routine with torch.cuda.empty_cache(), a few batches would randomly introduce loss values of 10^5 or higher, which would rapidly cause the parameters and loss to go to nan. This happened even if I clipped the gradients. It doesn't happen when I delete the empty_cache() function. What is going on here? It seems as though the GPU is being pushed to calculate things incorrectly by the empty_cache command.

Comment: That looks like you're running out of system RAM, which makes Jupyter misbehave (since it can't resize some internal buffer).

Comment: Hmm, but then why would this happen after several epochs, instead of at the beginning of training?

Comment: Memory leaks? Jupyter's buffer growing too large? Who knows.

Comment: Is there a way to monitor system RAM or buffer usage so that I can try to find the source of the leak?